How to iterate through each file on each volume of each disk?
In Windows kernel programming, I want to iterate through each disk, then iterate through all volumes on those disks, and finally print out the file paths of all files on each volume. How can I do this?
VOID GetAllDisk2() {
    NTSTATUS status;
    PZZWSTR deviceNaems = NULL;
    UNICODE_STRING str1;
    DEVICE_OBJECT deviceObject;
    FILE_OBJECT fileObject;
    WCHAR wcstr[512];
    ULONG index = 0;
    ULONG ltmp1, ltmp2;
    MM_COPY_ADDRESS mmAddress;

    status = IoGetDeviceInterfaces(&DiskClassGuid, NULL, 0, &deviceNaems);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
        return;

    str1.Buffer = wcstr;
    str1.MaximumLength = sizeof(wcstr);

    while (deviceNaems[index] != 0) {

        ltmp1 = wcslen(deviceNaems + index);
        str1.Length = sizeof(WCHAR) * ltmp1;

        mmAddress.VirtualAddress = deviceNaems + index;
        MmCopyMemory(wcstr, mmAddress, str1.Length, MM_COPY_MEMORY_VIRTUAL, &ltmp2);

        status = IoGetDeviceObjectPointer(&str1, GENERIC_READ, &fileObject, &deviceObject);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            // TODO ============


        }
        index += ltmp1 + 1;
    }

    KdPrint(("End insert."));
}

I tried using IorDeviceInterfaces () to obtain all DeviceNames, and then obtained the DeviceObject and FileObject for.

I would start by counting the number of files on each volume, and display that result. Then consider how long it would take to display that many names (100s of thousands or millions?).
